# Django django.core.exceptions.FieldError when using 'unaccent' on postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

Hi I am seeing this issue when I do:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'unaccent' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

My query:

```
qs = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .annotate(
                trigram = Greatest(
                    TrigramSimilarity('username', search_text),
                    TrigramSimilarity('first_name', search_text),
                    TrigramSimilarity('last_name', search_text))
                ).filter(
                    Q(username__unaccent__trigram_similar=search_text) |
                    Q(last_name__unaccent__trigram_similar=search_text) |
                    Q(first_name__unaccent__trigram_similar=search_text), trigram__gte=0.3
                ).order_by('-trigram')
            )
        return qs
```

I have install pyscopg2 as well however, I do not know what's causing this issue? I have already added the unaccent extension as well to my database. But I still see this error

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add `django.contrib.postgres`  to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings file and see if it helps

Comment: Yes that was the issuse! thanks for your help